# How to open this module war project to run it as "Run on server"

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

I have a   net-beans project inside net-beans I can right click on any of the module project and open it to run/build it as stand alone application,How can I achieve the same inside eclipse?

[image]

Comment: Right click on the server - Add and Remove, add your project and start the server. Sometimes this doesn't work, so I just install the war/ear on the server through manager

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse its: `right click -> run as`

The eclipse will show you the options of running depending on the type of your project:

For example to show the option `run as "Java Application "` your module must contain a class that has a main method.

Answer (score 0):

In Project Explorer window, right-click on the project and select Run As --> Run on Server

[Eclipse: Project Run on Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PArQt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Once you add your JAVA project to any IDE it auto identifies it if JARs are added correctly. You can simply right click on the project and use "Run As" => "Run On Server"

There is high chance that you will not see Run On Server option.

In such a case you have to take the WAR and manually place it on server using add/remove programme through manager.

I can add steps by steps screenshots for you if you need else way t should be easy.